# Data alignment and inheritance problem

Tags: c++, data-structures

Considering these structures on 64 bits :

```
struct base
{
  long a;
};

struct derived : public base
{
  long b;
  char c;
};
```

I get a size of 24 and a padding warning but I don't understand why.
For me, data with this kind of inheritance are aligned like that

```
a
b
c
```

So a is aligned on 8, b too and c is a char and is aligned on 1.
So what is the problem here, why the size is 24 ?

Comment: Please also post which compiler you are using and the exact warning message.

Comment: what does the "padding warning" say?

Answer (score 8):

The size is 24 so that when you make an array of `struct derived` the second element of the array will have 8-byte alignment for `base::a`.

Comment: Ah, this is a structure alignment ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the compiler choses to use a word size for all the elements to enhance running speed. In GCC, for example, you can force tight alignment using

```
__attribute__((packed))
```

to the struct definition. You can study [this GCC documenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes). However, I'm not sure what assumptions you can make regarding alignment when you use inheritance. In particular, if you use virtual functions, size may change because of some pointers added to the structure.